# Accessing attributes in functions within the class returns wrong values

Tags: c++, class, object, attributes, glm-math

I have a constructor

```
GameObject::GameObject(Node body){
    _body = body; 

    glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glm::vec3 velocity = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

};
```

and a member function

```
void GameObject::update(float dt) {
    this->position = this->position + this->velocity * dt;
}
```

After calling the constructor, I call the update function on the same object.

```
GameObject* go_water = new GameObject(water);
go_water.update(dt);
```

However, if I use debug mode in visual studio and a breakpoint within the update method, I see that this->positions contains all "-431602080.". Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You declared new variables in the constructor instead of setting the members.

```
GameObject::GameObject(Node body){
    _body = body; 

    position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    velocity = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
};
```

Or even better:

```
class GameObject {
  public:
    GameObject(Node body) : body{std::move(body)} {}

  private:
    Node body;
    glm::vec3 position{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    glm::vec3 velocity{0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
};
```